# Getting json-keys after user uploads the json file without submitting the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an HTML page with a form to upload JSON files. I want to extract the keys from the JSON file without submitting the page. Later in the same page, I want to use these keys as option fields in certain form inputs.
So I have JSON Array in the file which contains multiple JSON Objets. I want to get all the keys from that JSON object. {"foo": "bar", "baz": "baq"} where "foo" and "baz" are the keys. These keys I want to use further in my form.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code where we can see what you did?

Comment: Please provide some code and what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you understand with "keys"?

Assuming your JSON is: `{"foo": "bar", "baz": "baq"}`

If you understand "foo" and "baz" as keys, you need to use `filereader` api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the file contents, then use JSON.parse() method to convert the file to json object and then iterate the object to get the keys:

```
var keys = [];

for (var x in obj){
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) keys.push(x);
}
```

then use the keys array to generate whatever you need to.

Janis

Comment: Or use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the keys